# how do you write a c wrapper for a c++ class with inheritance

Tags: c++, c, class, inheritance, wrapper

I was just wondering if there was a way to create a c wrapper API for a c++ class that has inheritance.

Consider the following:

```
class sampleClass1 : public sampleClass{

  public:
    int get() { return this.data *2; };
    void set(int data);
}


class sampleClass : public sample{

  public:
   int get() { return this.data; }
   void set(int data) {this.data = data; }
}

class sample {

 public:
   virtual int get();
   virtual void set(int data);

 private:
   int data;

}
```

How would I wrap the sampleClass1 to make it work in a c context ???

thanks,

Comment: please define "to make it work in a c context?" what are you trying to do?

Comment: I mean for instance accessing the sampleClass.data member within a c context. Or accessing a sampleClass member from a sampleClass1 object within a c context.

Comment: What do you mean by "c context"? Do you want to call this code from C programming language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your `sample` should really get a proper `virtual` dtor.

Next, just add one free function with C-binding for each function which is part of the interface, simply delegating:

#### "sample.h"

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
typedef struct sample sample;
sample* sample_create();
sample* sample_create0();
sample* sample_create1();
void sample_destroy(sample*);
int sample_get(sample*);
void sample_set(sample*, int);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

#### "sample-c.cpp"

```
#include "sample.h" // Included first to find errors
#include "sample.hpp" // complete the types and get the public interface

sample* sample_create() {return new sample;}
sample* sample_create0() {return new sampleClass;}
sample* sample_create1() {return new sampleClass1;}
void sample_destroy(sample* p) {delete p;}
int sample_get(sample* p) {return p->get();}
void sample_set(sample* p, int x) {p->set(x);
```

#### "sample.hpp"

```
// Your C++ header here, with class definition
```

#### "sample.cpp"

```
#include "sample.hpp" // Included first to find errors
// Implement the class here
```

Comment: Hmmm, thought just of s.th. alike, but the _inheritance factor_ makes up the interesting part of the question, especially as vtables are involved. I'd say for a c interface the basic `struct`handle should provide some discriminator field.

Comment: Do i have to do this for every class that inherits the sample class if i need to access the top level class object?

Comment: You only have to create such C-linkage forwarders for those members you are interested in (Also, you might want to use a later class as the least-derived class the handle corresponds to). And perhaps you would want to have only one create-function, with arguments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Why a discriminator? We are delegating all the work of being discriminatory to the C++ side here.

Comment: Would I have to type cast the top level object to the lower levels in order to access the inherited type?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do so, wherever you know (and must acknowledge) that you are actually that you actually have a derived. In this example, that's nowhere though.