# C - casting pointer to pointer to void

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting, void

**EDIT** I don't need a solution to a problem, I want to know **if and why** I should prefer one thing over another. The function declaration **can not change**.

I have a C++ project and I need to write some code that will be called by code written in C. I have a class called `A`, and I need to implement a method that destroys such an object that was allocated by `new`, and nullify the pointer itself.

The declaration looks like this:

```
void destroy_A(void** a);
```

I need a `void**` so I can nullify `*a`.

Which of the following should I use (if any), **and why**?

```
delete *(A**)a;
delete *((A**)a);
delete (A*)*a;
```

**EDIT:** Maybe I wasn't clear: I don't know the technical terms, but I **do** use `delete` and not `free`, and the actual methods are called via code compiled in C. Otherwise, I wouldn't need the `void**`.

This is my CS faculty requirements, I didn't write the assignment :)

Comment: What was the `new` statement used actually? Usually there shouldn't be any cast necessary. Tough you might need to distinguish from `new()` and `new[]` an their corresponding `delete` and `delete[]` calls.

Comment: First of, **don't** zero out the pointer. It does not buy you anything and complicates your interface. And why do you need a cast, better use an opaque type for C (aka a forward-declaration of `A` as a `struct`).

Comment: @Deduplicator: What? Zeroing a pointer after deleting through it is common practice. It eliminates dangling pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not in the interface-function you give as a basic building block. There's a reason neither `free` nor `delete` do so.

Comment: @Deduplicator: This function the OP is trying to create is neither `free` nor `delete`. It is a wrapper around them, _not_ "a basic building block". Clearly, additional functionality is desired. Why not make that functionality the _only_ additional thing you'd do at your call site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you write a c wrapper for a c++ class with inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682425/how-do-you-write-a-c-wrapper-for-a-c-class-with-inheritance)

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, that's obviously not a duplicate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It **is** the basic building-block *on the C side*. Even though on the C++ side, it is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It is a duplicate for what the OP seems to try to achieve.

Comment: @Deduplicator: So? Questions are not just for the one particular person who writes them.

Comment: Yes. But that is the solution to the actual problem.

Comment: @Deduplicator: So what? Just because some answers are the same or loosely similar doesn't make the _questions_ duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of them work.  What you are looking for, in the end is

```
A* somePtr = ...; // get a pointer to your object
delete somePtr;   // delete the object it points to
```

Your three options are copied below, and each one is broken up into multiple lines to highlight what they are doing:

```
delete *(A**)a;

A** ptrToPtrToA a = (A**)a;
A*  ptrToA a2 = *ptrToPtrTo_a;
delete ptrTo_a;
```

No problem here.  We ended up properly dereferencing the object

```
delete *((A**)a);

A** ptrToPtrTo_a = (A**)a;
A*  ptrTo_a = *ptrToPtrTo_a;
delete ptrTo_a;
```

Hey, this one is exactly the same!  The only thing the parenthesis do is change the order of operations.  You happened to use the "native" order, so the parenthesis did nothing at all.

```
delete (A*)*a;

void* ptrTo_void = *a;
A*    ptrTo_a = (A*)ptrToVoid;
delete ptrTo_a;
```

This also worked, it just took a different path.

Which one is correct?  It's really a stylistic choice.  I will give you my stylistic rule of thumb: *always cast void pointers on separate lines*.  It makes it much clearer what is going on.

```
A* myObject = (A*)*a; // I prefer this one in this case, but what matters...
delete myObject;      // ... is that it is distinct from the delete...
*a = 0;               // ...not which cast is "best."
```

I like to do this because I find casting to/from void is a **very** tricky business when you really get down to it.  There are a lot of places where it can go wrong.  I like to create a clear line of code where I can mentally break apart all of my casting and make sure it does what I expect.  Since I specify the type of the variable I want (`myObject` is a `A*`, and there's nothing the compiler can do to make it otherwise if I mess up), I am more likely to get a compiler error if I do something wrong.  Its very easy to write casts from void where the compiler silently does a conversion you didn't expect.  Then you're fixing a runtime error instead of a compile time error.

I also like to use that cast line as a good place to put comments explaining *why* I think it is safe to do the cast in the first place, such as "the only void pointers passed to this function are those created by my function in this same .cpp file, so I KNOW exactly what type is safe to cast to."

Comment: Thanks! I thought so to, but my classmates disagree, citing http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html. Should I be worried about that? The part about "...relies on all pointer types having the same internal representation..."

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting one.  I would not worry about it in real life production code (I am not aware of a single compiler/platform where it would fail), in fact I happen to know it is a fundamental operation in both COM and JNI, two major standards.  In class, do what your professor tells you to.  I think, if you wanted to split hairs, the version I preferred survives the issue from the c-faq, so you can use that safely.  The only platform where that would make sense is one where one type, say `doubles`, are stored in a completely different bank of memory with a different sized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`delete ptr` is *never* going to compile in C. If it were, the first option would be correct, and the second option would be identical to it.

Comment: Use `free` instead, in connection with `malloc` an other functions from their family.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: That's UB; the object was allocated by `new`. Read the question!

Comment: 1. It isn't going to be compiled in C, it's going to be *called* by code compiled in C.
2. Why are the first two correct, and the last incorrect?

Comment: @Dori Right, well, that's not at all what your question says.

Comment: You're right, but I did try to edit it. Anyway, question 2 is what I really want to know...